# Генерация документации Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, документация

Проект построен на Vue компонентах. В каждом компоненте есть свои методы и т.д. Как писать под них доку с помощью JSDoc? JSDoc не может обрабатывать vue файлы. Была идея выносить все методы из компонента в helper.js там писать доку, а потом уже методы подключать в компонент (но это дико)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-vue.
А еще лучше посмотрите в сторону StoryBook.